# Google Cloud Terminal issues

Tags: ssh, terminal, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm having issues when connecting to our google cloud containers.

The terminal gets restricted to a certain size and it is behaving odd, when using vim for example the application hangs for 10-20 sec if you press Page-Down, but that's something i'm able to work around, the real issue is the following.

When typing a command and the width goes over the width-length of the prefixed size of the terminal, you suddenly don't know where your cursor is.

The same is for editing a file in vim and you start to scroll down or write a shellscript for example and the last line of the document gets updated, only the last line of the file gets updated and the scrolling behavior is suddenly very broken.

> This is what the pre-set size of the terminal looks like when editing
>   a file.

[image]

Setting the TERM enviroment variable to "xterm", "xterm-color" makes the colors and the "clear" function work but does not solve these issues.

If anyone else has experienced these issues and know how to fix them, sharing that knowledge would make life worth living again!

Comment: I also have issues sometimes editing k8s deployments in Vi - any chance these issues are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your glcoud components to the latest version solved this problem, now i'm able to run fullscreen vim and life is wonderful!

```
gcloud components update
```